# how to store values in localStoage using phone gap and accessing that value from chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am using the hybrid application using phonegap in iPad. Am launching the application from URL actually.In that URL some query strings are there.I want to store the URL some where.So i decided to store in localStorage using IOS coding and fetch the value in chrome localStorage. Is this possible ? ...or is there any other way to access that URL... Thanks in advance